# Does including many unused libraries affect efficiency?

Tags: c#, using

For example, in C#
Is

```
using System.X;
using System.Y;
using System.Z;
```

by any means slower than

```
using System.X
```

, even if the program only uses `System.X`?

And, if they doesn't matter, is it a better practice to include all the libraries that you would possibly use, or only those that are used in your code?

Comment: Thanks guys for marking duplicates.. I have searched but couldn't found questions related to that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by `efficiency`.

If you mean will it slow down my application at runtime, then **no**. Using directives are only used at compile time.

If you mean will it slow down my build step, then potentially it may take an extra few milliseconds if you have thousands of using directives in your file. But realistically **no**.

So.... wait for it.... **no**.